# Method not found in Xamarin forms UIKit.UIColor UIKit.UIColor.get_SystemBlueColor()

Tags: xamarin.forms

If I run my application in IOS simulator I got error in AppDelegate class[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKUVv.png)

on global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); this line.

Error is

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: UIKit.UIColor UIKit.UIColor.get_SystemBlueColor()
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init () [0x0000e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Forms.cs:127
>     at IsowheyFit.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0001c] in /Users/adequateinfosoft/Downloads/isowhey-fit/IsowheyFit/IsowheyFit.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:31
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
>     at IsowheyFit.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/adequateinfosoft/Downloads/isowhey-fit/IsowheyFit/IsowheyFit.iOS/Main.cs:17

Comment: which version of xamarin forms you are using?

Comment: I vaguely remember having the same issue. Is VS and XCode up to date?

Comment: Try to update your Xamarin.iOS version.

Comment: Xamarin forms version is 4.6.0.772

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.5

Comment: I am new in Xamarin and Visual studio, So Please tell me how to update Xamarin.IOS

Comment: Go to help-> about Microsoft Visual Studio to check which version of Xamarin.iOS are you uisng.

Comment: Xamarin.Mac 5.10.0.157 Xamarin.iOS 12.10.0.157

Comment: I could not update my VS in mac because it gives error while updating
"Error retrieving update information"

Comment: Follow the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/updater-troubleshooting?view=vsmac-2019) about the error "Error retrieving update information".